# CefSharp in WinForms - ExecuteScriptAsync or EvaluateScriptAsync doesnt work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp WinForms in my project and i cannot get it to execute a JS script from the CefSharp Browser Control
(I was to navigate to URLs though - so most of the CEF functionality works)
I tried following the tutorial at: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=BoundObject

I am using the following namespaces:

```
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using CefSharp.Internals;
```

and added references to the following assemblies (x64):

```
CefSharp.WinForms.dll
CefSharp.dll
CefSharp.Core.dll
```

but still I get the following error when I try to use one of the functions:
ExecuteScriptAsync or EvaluateScriptAsync

I get the following error:

```
'CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser' does not contain a definition for 'EvaluateScriptAsync' and no extension method 'EvaluateScriptAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

'CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteScriptAsync' and no extension method 'ExecuteScriptAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

can anyone direct me to the point i am missing? is there another API? maybe some reference dll that I am missing?
thanks

Comment: Did you install the `Nuget` package? Which Version specifically are you using? In newer versions those methods were made into `Extension Methods` as they can be executed on a specific frame. In a couple of cases I've seen people have trouble. Try getting the main frame first. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/45/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L245 for an example

Answer (score 3):

You may be missing one other namespace.  I would suggest you add:

```
 using CefSharp;
```

We were having the same trouble and found that we were simply missing this one. 
We now have:

```
using System.Text;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using CefSharp.Internals;
```

Answer (score 1):

CaptainBli is correct: you have to use "using CefSharp"

Probably you didn't expect it there, since it seems to be in another namespace: "CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser".

This is because EvaluateScriptAsync and ExecuteScriptAsync are extension methods